# Select from table, where x = y

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Okay so I'm building an app where I need to be able to pull information from a table called assignments. The information pulled from that table is dependant on what class is selected. I have it setup so when you add an assignment there is a spinner that has you select the class it is associated with which will place the id of the class into a column in the assignments table called classid. Is it possible to query the assignments table that only selects the assignments that has the value of class id equal to what the rowid is of the class being viewed?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column1, column2 FROM assignments WHERE classid = X